# How to achieve bold section titles in a Europass CV via europecv package?

Tags: sectioning, xetex, bold

I have a problem getting the section headers of my Europass CV to appear bold in the [`europecv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/europecv) package. Neither `\bf` nor `\textbf{}` seem to work. I am using XeLaTeX and this is how my document looks:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,narrow,german]{europecv}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1.2cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,fontspec}

\ecvlastname{}
\ecvfirstname{}
\ecvaddress{}
\ecvtelephone{}
\ecvemail{}
\ecvnationality{}
\ecvdateofbirth{}
\ecvgender{}

\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}

\ecvpersonalinfo[1em]

\ecvsection{}

\ecvitem{}{}
\ecvitem{}{}
\ecvitem{}{}

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

`\evcsection{Bla bla}` is what I want to have in bold like in this [sample CV](http://www.europass-info.de/fileadmin/template/downloads/Lebenslauf-Diplom-Kaufmann.pdf). 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `europecv` class is built for `pdflatex`: indeed it loads the `inputenc` package with the `utf8x` option. One can overcome the limitation with some tricks:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@inputenc.sty}{}       % pretend that inputenc has been loaded
\@namedef{opt@inputenc.sty}{utf8x}  % with the utf8x option
\makeatother

\documentclass[narrow,german]{europecv}

% fontspec doesn't want to see inputenc loaded,
% so now we pretend it hasn't been
\expandafter\let\csname ver@inputenc.sty\endcsname\relax
% europecv uses the \inputencoding command, that we neutralize
\providecommand{\inputencoding}[1]{}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1.2cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}

\ecvlastname{}
\ecvfirstname{}
\ecvaddress{}
\ecvtelephone{}
\ecvemail{}
\ecvnationality{}
\ecvdateofbirth{}
\ecvgender{}

\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}

\ecvpersonalinfo[1em]

\ecvsection{Bla Bla}

\ecvitem{}{}
\ecvitem{}{}
\ecvitem{}{}

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

You have to define a main font for the document, in order that the styles are correctly applied. The `helvetica` option doesn't do anything with XeLaTeX.

It's probably better to stick with `pdflatex` (or ask the class author to provide a XeLaTeX compatible version).

---

Actually, the patch to `europecv.cls` would be *very* easy: change the lines

```
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{ucs}
\RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

into

```
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
  \newcommand\ecv@utf[1]{#1}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \newcommand\ecv@utf[1]{#1}
  \else
    \RequirePackage{ucs}
    \RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \newcommand\ecv@utf[1]{{\inputencoding{utf8x}#1}}
  \fi
\fi
```

assuming that using `utf8x` is desirable: probably it would be best left as something to load in the document preamble. In this case the two lines after `\LoadClass{article}` should simply be omitted.

The definition of `\ecv@utf` appearing at the start of the file should be also omitted.

Comment: Thanks, egreg. I solved my problem using your suggested trick of simulating an included `inputenc`. I didn't want to bother with meddling with the `europe.cls` because the other solution was working very well anyway. Thanks a lot!